# basic javascript syntax question

Tags: javascript

What does the following javascript code mean? I guess it's defining a function within a function to make it look like OOP? Why the function can return multiple functions? what is the bracket at the end?

```
var grid_ui = function () {

    function setup_data_source() {}

    return {
        init: function () {},

        set_ds: function(rpt_headers, rpt_rows) {}
    } // return
}();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{ }` notation is called an object literal. It is same as:

```
a = new Object();
a.init = function() { };
a.set_ds = function(...) { };
return a;
```

and `return { }` returns an object.

The `function () { ... }();` is a self-invoking function: it creates an anonymous function them immidiately invokes it.

In your code, the self-invoking function returns an object of functions, which is a namespace pattern. The value of `grid_ui` now contains `{ init: ..., set_ds: ... }`, which is mentioned in `return`.

These concepts are very difficult to explain in one SO answer, so I will provide you some links:

- http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript/
- http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

it is defining an function then calling it and taking the return value and assigning it to `grid_ui`.

the value of grid_ui is now the object (also called a dictionary) containing the keys `init` and `set_ds`.

In javascript, you can define functions within functions and assign functions to variables.

Now you can make calls like `grid_ui.init()` and `grid_ui.set_ds("test", 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is OOP.  Functions are objects in JavaScript.

This code means that there is a variable, grid_ui, which evaluates to an object that has two "public" functions, init and set_ds.  init and set_ds also have a context which includes a "private" function, setup_data_source.

There are no brackets.